# Variables in httprequest post body

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to generate a jmeter script where a unique folder is created each time the script is run - adding a variable of some sort to the folder name, such as a username+timestamp, should be enough to guarantee uniqueness. However, jmeter is not resolving the variable to its value - although it is when the variable is read out of a csv file (which isn't suitable).

Basically, I'm editing the PostBody in the http request, as follows:

```
 {"alf_destination":"workspace://SpacesStore/90368635-78a1-4dc5-be9e-33458f09c3f6","prop_cm_name":"Test
 Folder - ${variable}","prop_cm_title":"Test
 Folder","prop_cm_description":"Test Folder"}
```

where `variable` is basically any variable I've tried so far (such as a random string, timestamp, etc.)

Can anyone suggest how to get the variable resolved?

Answer (score 32):

You can use jmeter (since 2.9 version) uuid  feature -> http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID

```
${__UUID}
```

and

> 1) If you want just 1 value for the whole test, add a "User Defined
>   Variables" Config Element to your test. This will be evaluated when
>   you load the test script the first time.
>
> 2) If you want to have the value change for every thread execution,
>   but stay the same during each thread instance: under your 'Thread
>   Group', add a 'Pre Processors -> User Parameters' to your thread group
>   - and add the variable there.
>
> Also, if you want the value to change each time the thread starts over
>   (each 'iteration' of the script within the thread group), you can
>   check the "Update Once Per Iteration" box on the User Parameters - and
>   it will get a new value each time it starts the thread over at the
>   beginning of th test script (within that thread group).

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201208.mbox/%3C004301cd853e$0c4a60c0$24df2240$@gmail.com%3E

Comment: In jmeter 2.11 this worked over any random variable inside a HTTP json POST body

Comment: It worked in jmeter 2.13, in request body by putting ${__UUID}

Answer (score 24):

With JMeter 2.9, the following works:

In HTTP Request Sampler, Tab "Post Body" add for example your JSON data and include the variables in it:

```
{"uuid":"${new-uuid}"}
```

`new-uuid` is a user defined variable.
This will send (from View Results Tree, Tab "Request"/"Raw"):

```
POST data:
{"uuid":"a1b2c3d4e5f6"}
```

Answer (score 5):

I did this by referencing a variable in the http request post body - `${formvalues}` - created using a beanshell preprocessor which is appended to the http request sampler.
 Beanshell contents:

```
double random = Math.random();    
String formvalues ="{\"alf_destination\":\"workspace://SpacesStore/90368635-78a1-4dc5-be9e-33458f09c3f6\",\"prop_cm_name\":\"Test Folder - ${uname}_" + random + "\",\"prop_cm_title\":\"Test Folder\",\"prop_cm_description\":\"Test Folder\"}";         
vars.put("formvalues",formvalues);
```

So this creates a folder with the username (`${uname}`, taken from the csv) plus a random number - it's crude as there could potentially still be cases where the script tries to create a folder with the same name as an existing one, but it will work for my case.

Answer (score 3):

suppose you have the value "NewYork" in jmeter variable "Location".

Use it like this in HTTP POST BODY DATA:

`{location:"${Location}"}` => which gets interpreted as `{location:"NewYork"}`